# How do I use SPI on LibreComputer RK3328 (Renegade)?

Tags: c++, debian, stm32f4

As a preface, I am familiar with embedded systems programming, specifically with STM and AVR chips. I am working on a project where I am using an STM32F4 chip to control stepper motors drivers. I'd like to use a single board computer to run a CPP program that has a CLI control interface and calculates reverse kinematics, then send commands via SPI to the STM32F4 chip, and receive status messages back. I have a LibreComputer Renegade (RK3328 chip) with a Debian Distro. How might I go about writing my CPP program to send the data out the SPI and receive messages from the SPI? From what I know, I can't just bitbang registers, and I have been so far unsuccessful in finding drivers to facilitate a hardware interface.

So far I have spent time on the Libre forums and in search engines looking for drivers and have not found any. I found a "tutorial" on how to "enable" the SPI (which didn't work) so I am looking for guidance on how to proceed.

Comment: See: https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/getting-started-with-stm32-how-to-use-spi/09eab3dfe74c4d0391aaaa99b0a8ee17?

Comment: I can set up the SPI on the STM32 just fine, it's the RK3328 that is confusing me.

Comment: A websearch on `RK3328 spi linux` produces [amongst others]: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/spi/spi-rockchip.c